# Making $USER identical to whoami command output

Tags: ssh

When I run `whoami` command user name is different and when I check the `$USER` variable the username is different, I want to set my `$USER` variable to the name which being showed by the `whoami` command. Please help.

Comment: Why is this tagged  ssh" ? Care to explain why you name is different than "whoami" shows? Is it because you use ssh to connect to another system and it is the name shown on THAT machine?

Comment: Can you include the output from `whoami` and `echo $USER` in your question? Then comment on where the names are probably coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why these would be different but you could easily fix it by putting the following line into your `.bashrc` file:

```
export USER=$(whoami)
```